# Access query asks for a year and month again

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a VBA code that checks if there are data in a year and month the user inputs, and by that it decides to which query to send the user.
this is the code:
       Sub macro1()

```
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim qdf2 As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim year As Integer
   Dim month As Integer

   Set dbs = CurrentDb
   Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("äëðñåú äåöàåú")
   Set qdf2 = dbs.QueryDefs("äëðñåú äåöàåú àí àéï èåøðéø áçåãù")

   year = InputBox("What year would you want to get data from?")
   month = InputBox("What month would you want to get data from")

   If Not IsNull(DLookup("[÷åã èåøðéø]", "[àãîéðñèøöéä ùì úçøåéåú]", "DateDiff('m', [úàøéê çæøä îäèåøðéø], DateSerial(" & year & ", " & month & ", 1)) = 0")) Then
   qdf.Parameters("[äëðñ ùðä]") = year
   qdf.Parameters("[äëðñ çåãù]") = month
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "äëðñåú äåöàåú", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
   Else
   qdf2.Parameters("äëðñ ùðä") = year
   qdf2.Parameters("äëðñ çåãù") = month DoCmd.OpenQuery "äëðñåú äåöàåú àí àéï èåøðéø áçåãù", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
   End If
   End Sub
```

The code works perfectly except that it doesn't input the year and month for the query, which means the user needs to enter the data twice, and he can enter different data on the second time, which doesn't solve the porblem.
I think the main reason is that both querys are built from other querys (because there relationship is to complicated to do on 1 query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `qdf.Parameters` collection only works when invoking the query using `qdf.Execute`.

If you're using `DoCmd.OpenQuery`, you should set parameters using `DoCmd.SetParameter`. Note that they need to be set again after invoking the first `DoCmd.OpenQuery`:

```
   DoCmd.SetParameter "[äëðñ ùðä]", year
   DoCmd.SetParameter "[äëðñ çåãù]", month
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "äëðñåú äåöàåú", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
```